# modeling error when estimating the parameters of the beta distribution

Tags: modeling, genetics, beta-distribution

After reading [*Basketball Beta and Bayes*](http://geofhagopian.net/MAM/BasketballBetaAndBayes.pdf), I started to think about parameter estimation with observational error.  If you are counting the number of successful and failed free-throws how can you account for score keeping errors?

I have a very similar problem where in addition to a set of outcomes (success or failure) I have a likelihood that the observation was correct.  It would analogous to the free-throw example if instead of seeing the free-throws you received two likelihoods (score or miss). How can I utilize this type of data to estimate the parameters of the beta distribution?  Ideally the beta distribution would be almost uniform if the likelihoods indicate a high probability of error.